# Assign a value to a specific element in a custom vector class. As a[5] = 3 C++

Tags: c++, vector, element, assign

I'm currently doing an exercise in school in C++.
The object is to write an own implementation of a vector class.

From the test file I should be able to give an element a specific value.

```
    a[5] = 7;              // element 5 of vector a should hold value 7.
```

I'm not sure if I call `a[5]` first or the `operator =`.

From my own class I have

```
int myvec::operator[](int i) {
    return arr[i];
}
```

Which returns the element at `i`. But I do not know how to give it the value of `= 7`.

What I've read there seems to be some kind of left operand built in to the `operator = (this)`?

So if anyone could help me to assign the value of element `i` I would really appreciate it.

Kind regards

Answer (score 4):

Instead of returning a new value, simply make it return a reference to the element:

```
int& myvec::operator[](int i) {
    return arr[i];
}
```

Also instead of `int` consider using `std::size_t` for the index.

Comment: Thanks =) Thought that something with reference should be added but wasnt sure where :)

Comment: What is the difference of using std::size_t over int?

Comment: @Keexarian std::size_t is guaranteed to be able to store the maximum size of any theoretically possible object of any size including arrays. Plus using integers doesn't make sense as negative values have no meaning as indexes.

Comment: You are right, size_t or `typedef`ing your own `myvec::size_type` is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `int myvec::operator[](int i)` with `int& myvec::operator[](int i)`

You should return the reference to the element to change it.

You may also want to write another overload for const as:

```
const int& myvec::operator[](int i) const /* const overload */
{
  assert(i >= 0);
  if(i > myvec.size() ) throw out_of_bound_exception;
  return arr[i];
}

int& myvec::operator[](int i)  /* Changeable */
{
  assert(i >= 0);
  if(i > myvec.size() ) throw out_of_bound_exception;
  return arr[i];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I know if it's the const function that executes or the other?

Comment: if you write for example `cout << mv[i] << endl;` from a function with prototype `void print_ith(const myvec &mv, int i)`, const overload would be called as the mv is const reference to object. On the other hand if you call `operator []` from a non const object or reference latter version would be called.